# What other function calls can freeze a smart contract like the pause() function?

Tags: contract-development, contract-design, contract-deployment, contract-invocation, contract-debugging

I'm learning to audit Ethereum smart contract code for clues if a smart contract can be frozen or not. Many smart contract creators claim their contracts are "unstoppable", but I'd like to know if there are ways they can back door into these contracts. With a quick search for "pause()" in any smart contract, I can see if it could be stopped or not.

- What other functions act in a similar way to pause() to stop a contract?
- Is there a way to obfuscate this pause() function in case if the developer wanted to hide it in their code?

Comment: Is `pause` a part of the Solidity language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- What other functions act in a similar way to pause() to stop a
  contract?

=> use the modifier that decides whether boolean **frozen** is true or false. If only frozen is false, the function can be executed.

- Is there a way to obfuscate this pause() function in case if the
  developer wanted to hide it in their code?

=> If developers didn't share their code, it is difficult for people to understand their bytecode in the transaction. However, not sharing code lowers the reliability of the smart contract.

If developers share their code, people are able to know its bytecode. **In that case, it is impossible to hide their code.**